# How do I deploy new test builds of a Windows Phone 8 app and keep the app data of the previous build?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, indexeddb

I'm working on a Cordova/Phonegap app, and whenever I use `cordova run` or the "Application Deployment" tool to install a new app on the Windows Phone, the data from the previous build is completely obliterated. Specifically, I have data in IndexedDB stores that I really don't want to have to completely recreate every time I update the app's content or code.

On Android (and I presume iOS) the WebSQL databases are still intact when I install a new build, so is there a way to preserve the app data on Windows Phone 8?

If so, how? If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PhoneGap. But instead of using the Application Deployment tool to install a new build you can use the Windows Phone Power Tools, available here: http://wptools.codeplex.com/

The power tools allow you to update an existing install with a new XAP package without losing any of your app data.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone power tools is indeed handy. But if you want to dead sure just before releasing that your app doesn't mess up on update, use Windows phone store beta submission. You can test your app by submitting first the previous version and installing/using it on device and then update that to newer version.

If you are updating your app from windows phone 7 to windows phone 8 by adding another xap package, power tool doesn't work. In this case you must use Windows phone store beta submission.